# Multivariate exponential smoothing and Kalman filter equivalence

Tags: kalman-filter, exponential-smoothing, filter

Suppose the time-series $X$ is hidden state Gaussian random walk and we observe $Y = X + e$,  where $e$ is gaussian white noise independent of $X$.

The Kalman estimator of $X$ in this case has a steady state closed form solution and corresponds to an exponential moving average smoother with constant smoothing parameter. The optimal smoothing parameter looks like $\lambda = \frac{p}{1-p}$  where $p$ is a quadratic formula of signal to noise ratio between $e$ and $\Delta{x}$. See [formula for closed form](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Kc6tnRHBwLcC&lpg=PA175&ots=I2VPQwXUGA&dq=kalman%20solu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btion%20random%20walk%20noise&pg=PA175&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=kalman%20solution%20random%20wa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blk%20noise&f=false) (by searching '*kalman solu‌​tion random walk noise*').

If we have instead *multiple independent* observations $Y_1, Y_2,...$, i.e. independent $e_1, e_2,...$ is there a closed form solution for the optimal estimator of $X$?    What would it look like?

If the $e_1, e_2$ were independent *and* identically  distributed (same standard deviation), I can imagine the best estimator for $X$ is to simply average the estimators obtained treating the problem as univariate for each $Y$.

If the $e_1,e_2,...$ have different variance, then some $Y$ series should have low weightings in the overall estimator as their signal to noise ratio is poorer. Perhaps the closed form solution is linear with coefficients proportional to each $Y$ signal to noise ratio.

Is there a known closed form solution? Google seems not to be too helpful on this problem.

Comment: formula for closed form:  books.google.com/books?id=Kc6tnRHBwLcC&lpg=PA175&ots=I2VPQwXUGA&dq=kalman%20solution%20random%20walk%20noise&pg=PA175#v=onepage&q=kalman%20solution%20random%20walk%20noise&f=false

Comment: First of all the constant smoothing parameter is achieved when the filter converges to the steady state. So in that respect exponential smoothing and kalman differ. Secondly I think the question requires clarification in the sense that when you mean Y1 and Y2 are they different time indicies or position in the vector Y for the same time?

Comment: Your observation noises $e_i$ are independent, but are your random walk $X$ increments independent? If they are, then you just have a bunch of 1-d independent filters and closed-form formula for 1-d case applies to each.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified but if the observation noise is independent of the model noise then I think you should first combine the Y estimates with simple observation variance weighted mean as specified here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean#Dealing_with_variance

after that apply kalman filter as if it is a univariate model. As a result you will have a lower observation noise hence a better estimate of x.